# Help needed finding $\int x\cdot e^{-x^2/a^2}\cdot J_1(x) dx $

Tags: integration

I would dearly love to have an analytical expression for the integral of

> $$\int x\cdot e^{-x^2/a^2}\cdot J_1(x) dx  $$

I tried via integration by parts but either I can't reduce the problem or I end up needing to differentiate $J_1(x)$ which I don't know how to do. Any help you can offer would be much appreciated. Thank you.

An engineer,

Comment: What is $J1(x)$ any expression in x

Comment: I think it is Bessel function of the first kind

Comment: The only help I can give is that $xJ_1(x)e^{-x^2}$ is even and the derivative of $J_1(x)$ is $1/2(J_0(x)-J_2(x))$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says no.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably no closed form to express the undefined integral $\quad \int x\: e^{-x^2/a^2}\: J_1(x) dx \quad $ with a  finite number of standard functions.

The defined integral 
$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty x\: e^{-x^2/a^2}\: J_1(x) dx  $$
can be expressed on a closed form :
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty  e^{-p\:t}\: J_1\left(\sqrt{t}\right) dt\qquad 
\begin{cases} 
x^2=t \\
p=\frac{1}{a^2}
\end{cases}
$$
This is the Laplace transform of $J_1\left(\sqrt{t}\right)$ :

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2} L_t\left[ J_1\left(\sqrt{t}\right) \right](p) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8 p^{3/2} }e^{-\frac{1}{8p}}\left(I_0\left(\frac{1}{8p} \right)  -I_1\left(\frac{1}{8p} \right) \right)$$
$I_0$ and $I_1$ are the modified Bessel functions of first kind and order $0$ and $1$.
$$\int_0^\infty x\: e^{-x^2/a^2}\: J_1(x) dx  = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\:a^3}{8}e^{-\frac{a^2}{8}}\left(I_0\left(\frac{a^2}{8} \right)  -I_1\left(\frac{a^2}{8} \right) \right)$$